# How to handle a user asking to answer an on hold question

Tags: discussion

I was reviewing a suggested edit to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77379/help-cant-find-this-font-type) and I noticed the user that suggested the edit made this comment:

> I can identify this but the system won't let me because of my low reputation. Please remove from hold.

The question was quite bad and was on hold (I edited the question a bit to translate some of the French that was mixed in it), but ultimately did nothing.

Is there something else I should have done? Even though the question doesn't meet the requirements for a font identification question, should this person still be allowed to answer it?

Comment: That was a horrible edit. I think you chose "Improve edit", where the better move would have been to *reject* and edit. On a related note: the same user suggests adding atool to [tag:font-identification] because it is "considered by many as the best desktop software ..." - he might be biased as it's his own, per his profile :)

Comment: That edit really should have been rejected and not improved.. he got +2 for that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nice catch! But no, there is nothing else you should have done. Font ID questions must still meet the requirements whether they are answerable or not. The same should apply for a question closed under any other reason; lots of questions that get closed are indeed answerable. They get closed because they are not a good fit for our format.

Comment: +1 because I agree

Comment: Worth noting the user has been answering those font-id questions with links to [his](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/76180/harris) font-id software (and [suggested an edit](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52315) adding it to the font-id tag wiki).

Comment: @Cai: I was wondering about that practice. I'm inclined to comment on a plain "this is the font"-answer, to ask how that answer was found. That way it could be *more* useful to others. However, this would reek of self-promotion - except that the OP *does* disclose the personal affiliation (which either is, or should be, a requirement in such cases).

Comment: @RadLexus I completely agree. I'm not completely sure disclosure in the users profile is enough though, how many people actually look at profiles? I feel a meta post coming on...

Comment: @Cai thanks for pointing that out, its been noted